BJT not switching properly
Image-1

Image-2

Image-3

Note:- The query is regarding the signals SHUTDOWN, TRIP_TEMP. Ignore the signals GATE_EN, MON_TEMP, ALARM_TEMP
Image-1, Image-2 and Image-3 are part of a single schematic
The Expected functionality of the circuit consisting these three images are:-
Case-1
-> When the SHUTDOWN signal becomes high in the U13 chip, Q10 must turn ON, then the collector of Q10 is pulled to ground and the gate of M2 must pull to ground, then Vgs will become negative and M2 turns ON
Case-2
-> When the SHUTDOWN becomes low, the Q10 must turn OFF, Gate of M2 and source of M2 will have same potential(Gate will be equal to VDD_IN because of pull-up). Hence, Vgs will be equal to zero and M2 must turn OFF.
Practically when tested using the hardware circuitry:-
VDD_IN is 28V
M2 is always ON when we are making TRIP_TEMP high and low(by external control just for testing of the IC). But what we are observing is VBE of Q10 is switching between 16V and 13V. We don't understand that how is even Q10 switching if the voltages are 16V and 13V across base-emitter when VBE is supposed to be between 0.6~0.7V. We have also placed a series resistor of 100 ohm to the base of Q10 and checked. But we are observing the same behaviour
Please tell what may be the reason for this behaviour of Q10.
We are suspecting that VDD_IN is being applied in reverse to the BJT. If that was the case, Q10 must have been in breakdown and the pins must have get shorted. But that didn't happen.

What is VDD_IN?  What is reversed breakdown voltage of zener D13?  What is M2 drain connected to?

But what we are observing is VBE of Q10 is switching between 16V and 13V across base-emitter  Question: how are you measuring this voltage, with a DMM or scope?   Is the positive probe on the base of Q10, and is the negative probe on the GND node which is also the emitter of Q10?

@FabioBarone I am measuring VBE using multimeter with positive probe on the base and the negative probe on the GND which is also the emitter of Q10

If D13 zener voltage is less than VDD_IN, then R8 will turn on Q10 and a very large current will from from VDD_IN through D13 and Q10.  This will cause heating in D13 an Q10, which may damage one or both of these components.

But what we are observing is VBE of Q10 is switching between 16V and 13V.

Response: If Q10 Vbe is greater than 0.7V, then Q10 is damaged.  Is it possible that Q10 has failed with a low-impedance from collector to base, and an open-circuit from base to emitter?  Is the zener voltage of D13 about 12V?  If so, then the 16 to 13V you are seeing is from:
VDD_IN - Vz  = 28 - 12 = 16.
The 13V could be due to SHUTDOWN pin going low when U13 output FLAG2 (open drain) goes low impedance to GND.
You need to put something (like a resistor) to limit the current in the path: VDD_IN, D13, Q10.

UPDATE 2024-05-25
Here is the circuit I am recommending based on your comments.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have tried to keep the component identifiers as per your schematic.  M3 represents the output stage of U13 that drives the node "SHUTDOWN".
Operation
When M3 is OFF, SHUTDOWN is high (5V) and this sets Q10 Vb to be very close to 5V.  This sets Q10 Ve to be ~4.2V, so current in R2 is about 2mA, which will be also flowing into the collector of Q10 by normal transistor action.  Assuming D13 is a 12V zener, then 1.2mA of that current will flow in R9, the remainder (about 0.8mA) in D13.  This causes gate-source voltage of M2 to be 12V, thus turning it ON.
The power dissipation in all the components mentioned, R9, D13, R8, will all be less than 20mW.  Q10 power dissipation will be slightly higher, about 25mW.
When M3 is ON, SHUTDOWN is low (0V) which turns off the collector current of Q10.  This then causes Gate-Source capacitance to discharge via R9, causing M2 to turn OFF.
The switching speed of M2 will be quite slow, probably in the range of 10 to 200 micro-seconds, but without knowing the type of load M2 is connected to I cannot accurately predict this.

Thank you for your answer. Again I have measured the resistance across the BJT terminals in the circuit. Rbe=3.45Kohm, Rce=3.89Kohm, Rcb=64ohm. I have also measured the resistance across the terminals before using it in the circuit and the resistance was in Mega ohms across each BE, CE and CB. As you said the behaviour might be due to passage of high current. You are suggesting to place a resistor in the path of VDD_IN, Q10 and D13, but can you say exactly at which node should i place. Also should i increase the value of R8 and R9. If yes, what should be the value.

And the part number of the zener diode is SMBJ5349B-TP. So yes, the zener diode rating is 12V

Insert a resistor in series with the collector of Q10.  The  value of it will depend on how fast you want to switch the M2..  is slow switching ok?  What is connected to M2 drain?

It is working now for 500 ohms. Thank you. No we are not switching it. Here we are using it for constant signal.

The other option is to put a resistor between Q10 emitter and GND.  The voltage at VCC5VO then sets the voltage at Q10 emitter when node SHUTDOWN (open drain) is not low impedance to GND.  This allows current in Q10 to be determined by this new resistor and VCC5V), rather than a zener and VDD_IN.  Select Q10 emitter current to be about 20mA, since you need about 12mA in the R9, and the remainder will flow in zener D13.  So R=4.3 / 20mA = 220r.

R8 could be changed to 10k without too much trouble, to reduce the current drain from the 5V supply.  R9 may also be reduced, depending on whether the slower turn off it causes is acceptable.
